# What controls does the built-in contacts app use?

Tags: ios, objective-c

In iOS, the built-in contacts app looks similar to what's displayed on this [example page](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/EnablingEditModeinaViewController/EnablingEditModeinaViewController.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH14-SW1). What controls are being used to create the initial view? Is it a table view? If so, how is the image on the left offset from the two rows?

What's happening behind the scenes to switch this view into edit mode? Are labels being replaced with textboxes or are the textboxes simply being set to editable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There are 2 ways to do things like this that I know**

---

**#1. That is UI TableView, but TableView with a custom TableView Header.**

Also it is `UITableViewStyleGrouped`
Just Init and setup the view include a UIImageView On the left side and three UITextField on the right side. 
like this

```
|----------| |---TextField---|
|---Image--| |---TextField---|
|----------| |---TextField---|
```

and set this view with:

```
self.tableview.headerView = yourViewWithImageAndTextField;
```

**2. Just try to use Apple's own `ABPersonViewController`**

1. [Apple's sample](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/QuickContacts/Introduction/Intro.html)
2. [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AddressBookUI/Reference/ABPersonViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Good luck to you

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an pre iOS7 **UITableView** in *UITableViewStyleGrouped* style, and a probably a custom cell to handle the image.